# how do you install libnss3-tools in eopkg

Tags: solus

How do you install this package : https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-amd64/libnss3-tools_3.26.2-1.1+deb9u1_amd64.deb.html or libnss3-tools in solus and solus uses eopkg. I'm really a newbie in linux environment, I can't seem to make it work the :

$ sudo eopkg install libnss3-tools

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a "time" getting that package installed in Solus.  I just started using Solus distro myself, but I am far from a novice linux user, just new to Solus.  Since you say you're a linux novice, I'll be explicit, so please don't think I'm talking down, I am just trying to be clear and give you reasons why I am doing what I'm doing, not just what to do.

I ran a quick repo search using eopkg, after updating it with "sudo eopkg update-repo", which updates eopkg's catalog.  Repos are where the online package storage sources are held.  Every package manager (Solus uses eopkg) has a search feature built in.  You gotta update before searching or you won't get the latest results available.

I found eopkg's by running "eopkg --help" (this works on almost all console commands, by the way, and will help you start using them)

eopkg uses the 'switch' named "search" to run keyword searches.  I recommend getting used to using wildcards, they will make your life easier when searching in text console (be careful anywhere else outside searching using wildcards, they are powerful).  In case you're not familiar with wildcards, the two you'll use most are * and ?.

```
* will get you everything at and following or preceding
```

> example, you are looking for libnss3-tools.  I enter libnss* because we're not sure you'll get v3 in Solus repo, so this will return anything starting with "libnss", i.e.`libnss3-tools, libnss3-dev, libnss4-dbg, etc...`

> searching *libnss will usually bring you back anything that ends with libnss, like `tools-libnss, dev-libnss, etc...`, but for eopkg search it will not work that way, it throws some type of repeat error.

```
? will get you anything just at that character, nothing else
```

> example, you're looking for libnss3-tools, searching "libnss?" will only return `libnss, libnss3, libnss4, etc...` unless whatever you're putting this into interprets everything following as a * anyway (like eopkg does)

So to get that answer, my final use of eopkg was

```
sudo eopkg update-repo <press enter>
eopkg search libnss* <press enter>
```

This gave me a result that does not indicate libnss3-tools as an available package to install.

You can add repos to the repo list, but since I'm new to Solus myself I have not found extra online repos to add to my repo list, or how to add them yet.  It may be that simple, but it also may be completely unavailable for Solus as a built package, leaving you to a whole other rabbit hole of learning to compile your own packages from source code.

...I'll look into adding repos and if that package is available in any repos besides the ones there by default.  I need to know this info anyway so I'll find out and come back.

> [REPOS] so adding and removing repositories is really easy, its done
> through the eopkg command.  The switches are right in the --help
> catalog.[END]

> [LIBNSS TOOLS] I'm not finding those anywhere for Solus, is using
> another certificate manager an option, such as openssl?  openssl is
> available in eopkg to install and has most of the tools listed in the
> 'libnss3-tools' package built into it. [END]